# Proof that a sleep function is impossible in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, multithreading

Put aside the discussion of the utility of a sleep function, I just would like to know (more likely, to confirm) that a sleep function is impossible in Javascript.

But of course I need to restrict the resources used to build the sleep function. What I mean by sleep function satisfies the following criteria:

1. The syntax must simply be:

   ```
   /*doing something before sleep*/
   sleep(int milliseconds);//completely pause the execution
   /*doing something after sleep*/
   ```
2. I do notice that we can use the trick of "fetching updates from other threads", such as using `new Date()`to check the condition of terminating the loop. So any similar acts, i.e. let the thread enter a loop controled by a boolean variable, and the boolean variable depends on information of some other thread, e.g. system time, server time, etc., should be out of the scope of the discussion. Therefore, the constraint imposed should be: build the sleep function using only Javascript's native functionality, which means the only resource of timing is essentially `setTimeout()`.

Well, intuitively I feel that building such function is impossible, because single thread can pause only by loops. However, with single thread execution, it is impossible to change the boolean variable (which determines the condition of exiting the loop) within the loop.

But this is obviously just a feeling, so I am just wondering, has there been any discussion of the actual possibility of such function in JS?

Comment: Sounds like you're just looking for callbacks.

Answer (score 1):

That is not a good question. *JavaScript* is a general word for similar languages. It's very simple to imagine (or even create) a JavaScript implementation with `sleep` function (useless though). That's one thing.

Secondly `setTimeout` does use system/server time. You can't have one without the other. So the answer to your question is: yes, just loop with time check (again: totally useless). Your second restriction is unrealistic.

The real restriction should be: sleep which does not use 100% CPU. In that case it is not possible in any major JS implementation.

All of that was in the context of synchronous sleep. However `setTimeout` **is** sleep. It's just asynchronous. Why is that a problem?

Answer (score 1):

Using Promises and the new ES6 generators this can just about be done. Looks like this:

```
sync(function* (){
    yield sleep(3000);
    console.log('more sleep');    
    yield sleep(3000);
    console.log('done sleeping');
});
```

Full code:

```
function sync(generator){
    var _generator = generator();

    function done(){
        var result = _generator.next().value;
        if(result instanceof Promise){
            result.then(done);
        }
    }

    done();
}

sync(function* (){
    yield sleep(3000);
    console.log('more sleep');    
    yield sleep(3000);
    console.log('done sleeping');
});

function sleep(ms){
    return new Promise(function(res, rej){
        setTimeout(res, ms);
    });
}
```

[JsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/aV46K/). (browser must [support JS Harmony](http://blog.chromium.org/2012/02/future-of-javascript-take-peek-today.html) features for this to work)

This does not actually block the Javascript event-loop/thread. It simply pauses the execution of the function passed to `sync`, and resumes it once the timeout completes.

Comment: that is cool. Using es7, it can all be compressed into one line (which can be compiled with traceur down into es5): `async function sleep(t){await new Promise((res) => {setTimeout(res, t)})}`

Comment: @superdweebie woa. that's quite nifty

Answer (score 1):

@levi: Your example is now "native" Javascript :)  At least if it is definded as ECMAscript 2015, that was finally approved this week, including the function*, yield* and yield statement.

Here I will show how to make **sleep()** called from several levels of functions.  This example draws a tree with THREE.js (just as eye candy), and uses sleep() so you can see it while it is build.  The THREE stuff with rotating scene, camera, lights, shaders and a rendering loop are hidden inside setup3D().

All the functions that can be paused must be defined as GeneratorFunctions, simply written as function*.  When first called it returns a GeneratorObject, but the body of the function is not executed.  It starts "sleeping" so to speak.  The .next() method will start executing the body until the next yield statement.

The function* sleep() sets the timer for a wakup call, then it yields (pauses) until wakeup executes .next().  When it wakes up from yield it returns like a normal function with all local data intact.

The main function* drawTree() draws a branch, makes a pause, and then splits into 3 parts, each part is a new smaller tree.  A very small tree is simply a leaf.
A GeneratorFunction can delegate execution to another GeneratorFunction with yield*.  It works just like a simple function call, but it can be paused with yield.

```
site = Setup3D(20);
sleepingTask = new drawTree(site.center, 7);
sleepingTask.next();

function* sleep(delay, task) {
    task = task || sleepingTask;
    var wakeup = function() {task.next()};
    setTimeout(wakeup, delay*1000);
    yield;
}

function* drawTree(root, size) {
    if (size<2) drawLeaf(root)
    else yield* drawBranch(root, size);
}

function* drawBranch(stem, size) {
    stem.add(new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.CylinderGeometry(size/12, size/10, size), 
        site.color(0.5,0.3,0.2)) .translateY(size/2));
    stem.add(new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.SphereGeometry(size/12), 
        site.color(0.5,0.3,0.2)) .translateY(size));
    for (var r of [1, 3, 5]) {
        var newStem = new THREE.Object3D();
        stem.add(newStem.translateY(size).rotateY(r).rotateX((20-r)/20));
        yield* sleep(0.1);
        yield* drawTree(newStem, size*(70+r)/100);
    }
}

function drawLeaf(stem) {
    stem.add(new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.CylinderGeometry(0, 0.1, 3), 
        site.color(0,1,0)) .rotateX(0.3).translateY(1.5));
    stem.add(new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.CircleGeometry(1), 
        site.color(0,1,0)) .rotateX(0.3).translateY(2));
}
```

**Multitasking** is also possible using sleep().  Here drawLeaf() is extended, so each leaf becomes a separate task.  Each leaf has a life of its own, it grows, sits, fades and falls.  The GeneratorObject for a leaf is added to the stem object, and is used as the second parameter to sleep, so the callback knows whom to wakeup.  The function* leafLife() is started from drawLeaf(), but drawLeaf() itself can be defined as a simple function, because it does not use yield or yield*.

```
function drawLeaf(stem) {
    stem.add(new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.CylinderGeometry(0, 0.02, 0.6), 
        site.color(0,1,0)) .rotateX(0.3).translateY(0.3));
    stem.add(new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.CircleGeometry(1/5), 
        site.color(0,1,0)) .rotateX(0.3).translateY(2/5));
    stem.leafTask = new leafLife(stem);
    stem.leafTask.next();
}

function* leafLife(stem) {
    for (var i=0; i++<9;)    { 
        yield* sleep(0.5, stem.leafTask);  
        stem.scale.multiplyScalar(1.2);
    }
    yield* sleep(10 + 30*Math.random(), task);
    for (var i=0; i++<25;)   { 
        yield* sleep(1, stem.leafTask);    
        stem.children[1].material.color.setRGB(i/25, 1-i/40, 0);
    }
    for (var i=0; i++<100;)  { 
        yield* sleep(0.05, stem.leafTask); 
        stem.translateY(-2).rotateX(0.3).rotateY(0.5);
    }
    stem.visible = false;
}
```

The full code in case you want to try yourself:

```js
site = Setup3D(20);
sleepingTask = new drawTree(site.center, 7);
sleepingTask.next();

function* sleep(delay, task) {
  task = task || sleepingTask;
  var wakeup = function() {
    task.next()
  };
  setTimeout(wakeup, delay * 1000);
  yield;
}

function* drawTree(root, size) {
  if (size < 2) drawLeaf(root)
  else yield* drawBranch(root, size);
}

function* drawBranch(stem, size) {
  stem.add(new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.CylinderGeometry(size / 12, size / 10, size),
    site.color(0.5, 0.3, 0.2)).translateY(size / 2));
  stem.add(new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.SphereGeometry(size / 12),
    site.color(0.5, 0.3, 0.2)).translateY(size));
  for (var r of[1, 3, 5]) {
    var newStem = new THREE.Object3D();
    stem.add(newStem.translateY(size).rotateY(r).rotateX((20 - r) / 20));
    yield* sleep(0.1);
    yield* drawTree(newStem, size * (70 + r) / 100);
  }
}

function drawLeaf(stem) {
  stem.add(new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.CylinderGeometry(0, 0.02, 0.6),
    site.color(0, 1, 0)).rotateX(0.3).translateY(0.3));
  stem.add(new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.CircleGeometry(1 / 5),
    site.color(0, 1, 0)).rotateX(0.3).translateY(2 / 5));
  stem.leafTask = new leafLife(stem);
  stem.leafTask.next();
}

function* leafLife(stem) {
  var i, task = stem.leafTask;
  for (i = 0; i++ < 9;) {
    yield* sleep(0.5, task);
    stem.scale.multiplyScalar(1.2);
  }
  yield* sleep(10 + 30 * Math.random(), task);
  for (i = 0; i++ < 25;) {
    yield* sleep(1, task);
    stem.children[1].material.color.setRGB(i / 25, 1 - i / 40, 0);
  }
  for (i = 0; i++ < 100;) {
    yield* sleep(0.05, task);
    stem.translateY(-2).rotateX(0.3).rotateY(0.5);
  }
  stem.visible = false;
}

function Setup3D(rotationsPerMinute) {
  var p = {};
  p.scene = new THREE.Scene();
  p.camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);
  p.camera.position.z = 50;
  p.camera.position.y = 30;
  p.renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
    alpha: true,
    antialias: true
  });
  p.renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
  document.body.appendChild(p.renderer.domElement);

  var directionalLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffaa, 0.7);
  directionalLight.position.set(-1, 2, 1);
  p.scene.add(directionalLight);
  p.scene.add(new THREE.AmbientLight(0x9999ff));

  p.center = new THREE.Object3D();
  p.scene.add(p.center);
  p.color = function(r, g, b) {
    return new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
      color: new THREE.Color(r, g, b),
      vertexColors: THREE.FaceColors,
      side: THREE.DoubleSide
    });
  };

  var render = function() {
    requestAnimationFrame(render);
    p.renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
    p.scene.rotateY(rotationsPerMinute / 60 / 60);
    p.renderer.render(p.scene, p.camera);
  };
  render();

  return p;
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #a0a0f0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/r71/three.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply put - no, you cannot have a global "sleep" style function that will prevent Javascript running within a browser window.

OK, that's the simple answer, the more complicated one is that it depends entirely upon what you're trying to achieve.  The way you'd implement something that could simulate a sleep would be to have a single function that runs your main logic which calls itself using a setTimeout (you need to record a datum to ensure your timing is correct), you can then delay calling itself by the sleep period.

It is purely situational however and you have to be sure to code all of your logic into that single function as other things could run in parallel.